# Prolog recursive list of lists

Tags: list, sorting, recursion, prolog

Right now I am stuck trying to define a predicate `ascending/1` that takes a list of lists and determines if the lists are sorted within the list of lists in increasing size. I made a helper predicate `smaller/2` and takes in 2 lists, for example A and B' and will succeed if A is less than or equal to B in length and fail otherwise. What my question is, is how do I recursively call `smaller/2` within the predicate `ascending/1` assuming that `smaller/2` is implemented correctly? Im new to prolog so the syntax gets me confused. So far I have:

```
%empty list%

ascending([]).
ascending([Z]) :- smaller ([_|Z]), [_,_|Z]).
```

im trying to take the head of the list of lists and compare it to the second head of the list of lists.
also I do not want to use any other predefined functions only my helper predicate.

Comment: If `sort/1` should succeed for sorted lists, why not call it `sorted/1` or even better: `ascending/1`?

Comment: I could, it was just a name I have given it though

Comment: Names influence what you think - and here in Prolog you really have to think differently. Thus a misleading name might influence whether or not you will understand Prolog.

Comment: Very true, I will change it. On the other hand, is the way I am using smaller correct?

Comment: ok so use that instead of smaller?

Comment: so my question is how to I extract the first and second list out of the list of lists for comparison? and then how do I move from the second to third lists and so on?

Comment: @Frank, You do realize that `[Z]` is a list of only one element, right?

Comment: Actually no i didn't know that. How would you represent a list of lists?

Answer (score 2):

So, here is my answer - [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26726484/772868) came up in the meantime.

Before answering your original question, I will look at ascending lists of integers. The reason: It's just simpler to distinguish here between the list and its elements.

#### Find a *descriptive* name

Avoid imperatives, since (pure) Prolog predicates do nothing. Or at best they describe relations. But they don't sort or add or compare. In our case `ascending/1` might be an ideal name, `sorted/1` is less ideal since it somewhat suggests that somebody will sort things. So there is still a tiny imp (imperative entity) around.

#### Give some test cases

This will often help to clarify the meaning to you. And always remember: Now, your mind is fresh, so put an effort to add meaningful test cases. Later you will become tired and less attentive, but let me assure you: Your Prolog system will never get tired. So you can put those test cases *at the end* of your file:

```
?- ascending([1,2]).
?- ascending([1,1,2]).
?- \+ ascending([2,1]).
```

#### Start with a predicate that is too general

A (trivial) first try might be:

```
ascending(_).
```

This definition succeeds always! Clearly too general. So how can we specialize it? Adding a single goal will not work. But since it should be a list - we can start with the definition of a list.

```
ascending([]).
ascending([_E|Es]) :-
   ascending(Es).
```

Now, this is still to general, we want a list of integer with certain properties. So again we need to specialize this definition. What we want is that for `Es = [A,B,C]` the goals `A #=< B, B #=< C` hold.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
ascending([]).
ascending([E|Es]) :-
   E #=< F,
   ascending(Es).
```

Did you see that warning about `F` being singleton? Prolog hates such variables, too often they are typos.  And in a sense Prolog is right. We should relate `F` to something else. It should be the next element in `Es`.

```
ascending([]).
ascending([E|Es]) :-
   lesseq_than_first(E, Es),
   ascending(Es).

lesseq_than_first(_, []).
lesseq_than_first(E, [F|_]) :-
   E #=< F.
```

We could "optimize" this definition. But this form better reveals what it is about: It is a list, were elements are interconnected.

So much for ascending lists of integers. But, how essential was the fact that the list was ascending, couldn't a descending list almost possess the same definition? Isn't this a waste of our precious attention if too many names fill up our overloaded mind?

We had essentially a chain of values that were interconnected with `(#=<)/2` which could be any other relation. So instead of `ascending([1,2,3])` we could have said `chain(#=<, [1,2,3])`. (BTW: Is this a nice name? Or do you have a better one?)

```
chain(R_2, []).
chain(R_2, [E|Es]) :-
   rel_to_first(R_2, E, Es),
   chain(R_2, Es).

rel_to_first(_R_2, _E, []).
rel_to_first(R_2, E, [F|_]) :-
   call(R_2, E, F).
```

With this general definition, we can now go back to your original predicate: `smaller/2` is not an ideal name. Maybe `shorter_than/2`?

```
shorter_than([], _).
shorter_than([_|Es], [_|Fs]) :-
   shorter_than(Es, Fs).

sorted(Ess) :-
  chain(shorter_than, Ess).
```

After having written this I realize that I forgot to illustrate another good advise: Play with the top-level! But this will not fit into this answer...