# Prolog - How do I get the tail to not be null

Tags: sorting, prolog, failure-slice

> I have the following problem:
>
> Define a predicate `sorted(LL)`, that is satisfied when the list `LL`
>   contains other lists that are sorted in order of increasing length.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> ?- sorted([[],[1],[1,1],[1,1,1]]) -> yes.
> ?- sorted([[],[1],[1,1]]) -> yes.
> ?- sorted([[1],[],[1,1],[1,1,1]]) -> no.
> ```

And I have this code so far:

```
% shorter/2

shorter([],_).
shorter([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- shorter(T1,T2).

% sorted/1

sorted([]).
sorted([_]).
sorted([L1,L2 | T]) :- shorter2(L1, L2), sorted([L2,T]).
```

The problem is contained in the above line: `sorted([L2,T])`. When only one element is left in the list of lists, that call will append an empty list `[]` because of which shorter/2 will fail. It is depicted in the following SWIPL trace.

```
[trace]  ?- sorted([[1],[2,3]]).
   Call: (6) sorted([[1], [2, 3]]) ? creep
   Call: (7) shorter2([1], [2, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (8) shorter2([], [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) shorter2([], [3]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) shorter2([1], [2, 3]) ? creep
   Call: (7) sorted([[2, 3], []]) ? creep <-- empty list appended
   Call: (8) shorter2([2, 3], []) ? creep
   Fail: (8) shorter2([2, 3], []) ? creep
   Fail: (7) sorted([[2, 3], []]) ? creep
   Fail: (6) sorted([[1], [2, 3]]) ? creep
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in the last clause of the `sorted/1` predicate, which should be:

```
sorted([L1,L2| T]) :- shorter(L1, L2), sorted([L2| T]).
```

Answer (score 3):

@PauloMoura already gave you the right answer. Is there anything to learn about this? How did you encounter that problem? And how can you locate such problems systematically? I assume that you did not jump into the debugger to look at all those traces for sheer curiosity and a low on supply of animated gifs.

You rather encountered *a problem*. That is, you had the goal `sorted([[1],[2,3]]).` which you expected to succeed, but it did not.  So you had here some **unexpected failure**.  Sometimes also called **insufficiency** or **incompleteness**.  This means that the definition for `sorted/1` is too specialized, it describes a set of solutions that is too small — at least it misses `sorted([[1],[2,3]])`.

It often helps to minimize the problem, first. Also `sorted([[],[3]])` fails, although we expect it to succeed. And `sorted([[],[]])` even loops.

### Understanding non-termination

Loops? That's often even easier to localize in a pure Prolog program. I will add goals **`false`** and goals like **`T = []`** into the program. The resulting program fragment (called a [failure slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)) certainly will become completely dysfunctional. But it will retain a very nice property. For: if this new fragment loops, then also the original program will loop. Here is that program that still loops:

```
?- sorted([[],[]]), false.

sorted([]) :- false.
sorted([_]) :- false.
sorted([L1,L2 | T]) :- T = [], L1 = [], L2 = [],
   shorter(L1, L2),
   sorted([L2,T]).

shorter([],_).
shorter([_|T1], [_|T2]) :- false,
   shorter(T1,T2).
```

in other words:

```
sorted([[],[]]) :-
   shorter([],[]),
   sorted([[],[]]).
```

So, procedurally speaking, that rule does not (always) reduce the length of the list.

### Concluding reading

Another way to understand the problem is to read the recursive rule **right-to-left in the direction the arrow is pointing**.  Actually, `:-` is meant to symbolize ←, well, 1970s style (listen to this [French 1972 summerhit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfdLh0MHqKw) <s>to</s> until you understand). So let's try this. I will read:

```
sorted([L1,L2 | T]) :- shorter2(L1, L2), sorted([L2,T]).
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ starting here
```

I start on the right side and interpret this as:

> Provided, `sorted([L2,T])` is true.

Maybe some extra remark: Now, you might get pretty uneasy. You might say: Who knows this? Maybe that is not true at all! But the point is, it's just conditional. OK?

> and provided `shorter(L1, L2)` is true
>
> ---
>
> then, we can conclude that `sorted([L1, L2|T])` is true.

So we take a list of length 2 as granted and conclude that a list of length 2 or more holds as well.

But where do we actually state that a list of length 2 holds? There is no other place than this rule. Thus: Nowhere is this stated. And thus lists of length 2 or longer will **never** be sorted.